# Asp.net to Facebook Apps( Any Button Working)

Tags: asp.net, html, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I trying to do app on facebook and All(.net button html button javascript button ) buttons dont work. I looked for another button which  but it didnt used anymore! which buttton can ı use or how can add working button asp.net to facebook app??

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your Facebook app lives in an iframe then all buttons/controls including asp.net ones are supported. My recommendation is to test your app outside of the Facebook iframe on the server which your page lives and ensure that the event handlers are firing as expected.

If that works as expected on your server, then I would use a browser developer tool [F12 -IE/Chrome/Firefox] to see if there are any errors are present which would prevent the page from loading correctly and resolve those and you should be fine.

Comment: public partial class _Default : CanvasIFrameBasePage
{
    
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.RequireLogin = true;
       
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = base.Api.Users.GetInfo().name;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Label1.Text = base.Api.Users.GetInfo().last_name;
    }
}